# Show that $f^2(x) = (f(x))^2$ also has an essential singularity at $z_0$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have been looking for a proof of this and I can't find anything that helps me.

Suppose that $f$ has an essential singularity at $z_0$.

Show that $$f^2(x) = (f(x))^2$$ also has an essential singularity at $z_0$.

I know that if f has an essential singularity at $z_0$ then $f$ can be represented as $$f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a_n(z-z_0)^n$$ where $a_n \neq0$ for an infinite set on which $n<0$.

Do I continue by commuting the product of the sums?

Really need help with this thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ has an isolated singularity at $z_0$ then

$f$ has a removable singularity at $z_0$ iff it is bounded in $\{z: 0<|z-z_0| <r\}$ for some $r>0$

$f$ has  pole at $z_0$ iff $|f(z)| \to \infty$ as $z \to z_0$.

$f$ has an essential singularity at $z_0$ iff $z_0$ is neither a removable singularity nor  a pole.

Can you use these facts to prove your result?

Comment: so here $|f(z)|$ is finite as $z\rightarrow z_0$ and $z_0$ is unbounded in $z:0<|z-z_0|<r$ for some $r>0$

Comment: @GavinK14 Use the fact that $f$ is bounded if $f^{2}$ is bounded and $|f(z)| \to \infty$ iff $|f^{2}(z)| \to \infty$. In other words, $f$ has  pole iff $f^{2}$ does and $f$ has  a removable singularity iff $f^{2} $ does. Conclude that $f$ has an essential singularity iff $f^{2}$ does.

Answer (score 1):

if $f(z)$ has an essential singularity at $z_0$

then $f^2(z)$ has an essential singularity at $z_0$ also.

I came across a method detailed below but it doesn't appear valid.

Seems appropriate if we investigating an essential singularity of $exp(f(z))$

Take $c \in \mathbb C$

By Casorati-Weistrass theorem there is a sequence $z_n \rightarrow z_0$ such that

$f(z) \rightarrow \sqrt{c}$

So $f^2(z) \rightarrow c$

Since this is true for all non-zero $c$ then $f^2(z)$ must have an essential singularity at $z_0$